# How does doc_values of Lucene is implemented?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, mmap, page-caching

I saw a ES documentation of "doc_values" http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html saying

"Doc values are built at index time, not at search time", so what will be built if using doc_values?

"doc values are prebuilt and much faster to initialize", why it is much faster?

"but without the heap memory usage",so using the page cache?

Can somebody explain to me how doc_values is implemented and when should I use?I check my heap usage with jstat periodically,and I can see that I still have a plenty of space to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Doc values are built at index time, not at search time", so what will be built if using doc_values?

There are two types of workloads for which we need a columnar view on top of the data: sorting and aggregations. And in the current version of Elasticsearch there are two cases:

1. the field is only indexed. In that case if you start sorting/aggregating on a given field, data will be lazily uninverted and put into a cache at search time so that you can access values given a document ID. This means that an inverted index such as

`foo -> 0, 1
 bar -> 1`

will be transformed into the following data-structure

`0 -> foo
 1 -> foo, bar`

2. the field has doc values enabled. In that case data will be stored in a columnar format at index time. Everything that you will need to do at search time will be to load some tiny metadata about your field and how it is encoded. Then data will be read directly from disk (relying on the filesystem cache for performance).

> "doc values are prebuilt and much faster to initialize", why it is much faster?

This uninversion process that I mentioned is actually very CPU and I/O intensive. The result is put in a cache but the first access is still slow and this will hurt the latency of all queries that run right after a large merge. You could fix this issue by loading fielddata eagerly but even though it will make response times better, it is moving the issue elsewhere and changes to your index will take longer to become visible since elasticsearch will wait for field data to be loaded before the new point-in-time view on the index is available for search.

On the other hand with doc values, you will only need to read some tiny metadata from disk and that's it.

> "but without the heap memory usage",so using the page cache?

Exactly! Doc values require very little heap memory, mostly metadata about field field and how things are encoded on disk. The rest is read directly from disk and relies on the filesystem cache for performance.

> Can somebody explain to me how doc_values is implemented and when should I use?I check my heap usage with jstat periodically,and I can see that I still have a plenty of space to use.

This is a bit complicated because there are different cases... for instance:

- depending on the type of the field (numeric vs. string)
- whether the field is single or multi-valued
- the cardinality of the field
- some patterns of the data... for instance we check for common divisors when encoding numeric fields in order to have a more efficient compression if all values share a common divisor. This typically happens if you encode timestamps with second or day precision since all values will be multiples of 1000.

But in practice, the important thing to know is that it's basically a very large mmap'ed file that is read sequentially, so even though disk-based, it's still friendly to your I/O system.

If this is something you are interested in, [you can read more about it](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene410/Lucene410DocValuesFormat.html)

Regarding when you should use doc values, I think you should enable doc values on all fields that you plan to sort or aggregate on. There is an ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8312) about enabling doc values by default in the next elasticsearch major version.

Comment: Can you please describe "In that case data will be stored in a columnar format at index time" part more?

Comment: The format is described here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene410/Lucene410DocValuesFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Simon Willnauer has a presentation about DocValues at Lucene Revolution 2011, so watch [his presentation for a 40 minute long introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLUgEpJcG40) about what DocValues are and why they are neat.

Doc Values is an optimisation for all the "other things" that modern search platforms do in addition to search, such as faceting, highlighting, etc.

The Solr Community Wiki also has a [description of DocValues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues) and what their usage is intended for:

> For other features that we now commonly associate with search, such as sorting, faceting, and highlighting, this approach is not very efficient. The faceting engine, for example, must look up each term that appears in each document that will make up the result set and pull the document IDs in order to build the facet list. In Solr, this is maintained in memory, and can be slow to load (depending on the number of documents, terms, etc.).
>   In Lucene 4.0, a new approach was introduced. DocValue fields are now column-oriented fields with a document-to-value mapping built at index time. This approach promises to relieve some of the memory requirements of the fieldCache and make lookups for faceting, sorting, and grouping much faster.

Their implementation is available in [org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.10.2/org/apache/lucene/index/DocValues.java#DocValues) and in each field type that supports using DocValues (each field type has to use DocValues explicitly).

Comment: Thanks.I will check the presentation.